# How to display particles on android?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, android-ndk, particles

I'm writing a opengl es program (NDK) on android and I need render some particles.
Could anyone tell me how to display particles on android?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey , See this, Building a particle system on Android http://androgeek.info/?p=331

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Point Sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444429/do-opengl-point-sprites-work-in-android).